# URDF joint problem

Tags: urdf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have created a URDF for IRB4600 60_2-05. When i checked the URDF with the original robot and echo the joint_state topic to see the joint positions. All joints matches with the positions with the positions of joints in real teach pendant of ABB but only difference is with joint 3.Difference between the 3rd joint position in RVIZ and in the original robot (can be seen through teach pendant) is exactly the same which is the present position of joint 2. It seems that in RViz it keeps on adding the joint 2 position in the joint3.Please let me know where is the problem in the URDF   !

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/262364/urdf-joint-problem/) by [Muneeb](https://answers.ros.org/users/29399/muneeb/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2017-05-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please see #q226402.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-05-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Muneeb](https://answers.ros.org/users/29399/muneeb/) on 2017-05-23**:
I always wonder what is the purpose of this argument"J23_coupler" ! now i know .Thanks
I just set this argument false .And now joint3 in RViz and Real robot matches .

**Comment by [Muneeb](https://answers.ros.org/users/29399/muneeb/) on 2017-05-23**:
Abb_irb4600_support package is working ok according to my understanding. Is there a way to validate it or can i add it to abb_experiment_repo for the other people to use.so that i may know if there is any problem with it.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-05-23**:
I must not have been paying attention when answering your question, but there is already an ABB IRB4600 support package that includes a model for your 60/2.05, see [abb_irb4600_support](http://wiki.ros.org/abb_irb4600_support).